# mark options as selected in multi select using json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an edit form in a jQuery modal dialog. It has a multi-select box populated straight from a db. The record I'm editing comes from the database using json. There's a field named `problemids` which has comma delimited ids.

The multiselect looks like this:

```
<select name="Problems" size="5" multiple="multiple" id="Problems">
    <option value="26">Backup battery error or cannot hold correct time.</option>
    <option value="22">Battery contacts damage</option>
    <option value="20">Belt clip damage</option>
    <option value="31">Cannot flash firmware</option>
    <option value="32">Cannot load task</option>
    <option value="34">Case damage</option>
    etc...  
</select>
```

And the json return looks like this:

```
[{
    "ModelID":33,
    "AccountID":1,
    "RandomID":"lo9876yhgbvfdr54",
    "ManID":5,
    "Model":"5090",
    "ProblemIDs":"22,26",
    "Active":true,
    "DateCreated":"2/27/2012 5:35:00 PM",
    "DateUpdated":"10/26/2012 2:04:00 PM",
    "UpdatedBy":6998,
    "CreatedBy":null
}]
```

And my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/edit-model.asp",
    cache: false,
    data: { recordid: recordid, rid: rid, crud: crud },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An error occurrred! " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $("#edit-dialogForm #RecordID").val(data[0].ModelID);
        $("#edit-dialogForm #RID").val(data[0].RandomID);
        $("#edit-dialogForm #ManID").val(data[0].ManID);
        $("#edit-dialogForm #Model").val(data[0].Model);
        if(data[0].Active){
            $('#edit-dialogForm input[name="Active"]:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);
        }else{
            $('#edit-dialogForm input[name="Active"]:eq(1)').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

How can I mark items as "selected" in my multiselect?

Comment: Your selector has an `input[name="Active"]`, though no input with name 'Active` is to be seen, then you try to set a check property on an input, though you probably want to set an option as selected in the `select[name="Problems"]` element, right?

Comment: @dbf Correct. To avoid confustion I should have shown all the fields in my form. The "Active" refers to 2 radio buttons which sets a flag to true/false.

Comment: Sound helpful, I sort of quit _interpreting_ or _assume_ stuff you probably didn't wrote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/TXcgh/

```
var data = {
    "ModelID":33,
    "AccountID":1,
    "RandomID":"lo9876yhgbvfdr54",
    "ManID":5,
    "Model":"5090",
    "ProblemIDs":"22,26",
    "Active":true,
    "DateCreated":"2/27/2012 5:35:00 PM",
    "DateUpdated":"10/26/2012 2:04:00 PM",
    "UpdatedBy":6998,
    "CreatedBy":null
};
$.each(data.ProblemIDs.split(','), function(index, element){
                     $('#Problems').find('option[value="'+ element +'"]').attr('Selected', 'Selected');
});
```

**UPDATE**: Modify your success callback like below

```
success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $("#edit-dialogForm #RecordID").val(data[0].ModelID);
        $("#edit-dialogForm #RID").val(data[0].RandomID);
        $("#edit-dialogForm #ManID").val(data[0].ManID);
        $("#edit-dialogForm #Model").val(data[0].Model);
        if(data[0].Active){
            $('#edit-dialogForm input[name="Active"]:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);
        }else{
            $('#edit-dialogForm input[name="Active"]:eq(1)').prop('checked', true);
        }
        $.each(data[0].ProblemIDs.split(','), function(index, element){
                     $('#edit-dialogForm #Problems').find('option[value="'+ element +'"]').attr('Selected', 'Selected');
        });
    }
```

Comment: This will work but I'm embarrassed to admit I don't know how to put my json response into a variable like you have. Otherwise I understand what your code is doing. Also, what if there isn't a trailing comma in the ProblemIDs?

Comment: You don't have to put it in a different variable, you already have this in a variable called data in your success callback.

Comment: Great! That worked. I thought I tried that last night but I was getting a "Cannot call method 'split' of undefined" error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Option value in Select Tag Should be Equal to the values in array or the value we are marking as selected from jquery

$('#updatecategoryname').multiselect('select', array);

[`Here Is The Example of Multi Select`](https://jsbin.com/wuvixoqihu/edit?html,js,output)